# Fastest way to compute a subset of columns of the pseudoinverse of a scipy.sparse matrix

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

I am looking for the best way to compute a subset of the columns of the pseudoinverse of a sparse matrix `A`.  Here are some relevant facts:

1. `A` is a sparse `NxN` matrix that has a single zero eigenvalue with known eigenvector
2. I only need `M < N/2` columns of the pseudoinverse
3. The pseudoinverse is a dense matrix

I am currently using `scipy.linalg.lstsq(A,Id)` (where `Id` is an `NxM` submatrix of the `NxN` identity matrix), but I suspect there is a better way to do this.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**Update:** Since there is only one zero eigenvalue, it turns out to be faster to create an invertible augmented `(N+1)x(N+1)` matrix and use `scipy.linalg.solve`.  However, this is still not taking advantage of the sparsity of `A`.

Comment: `scipy.sparse.linalg.inv` says 'If the inverse of A is expected to be non-sparse, it will likely be faster to convert A to dense and use scipy.linalg.inv.'

Comment: I am trying to increase N as much as possible, and at some point working with the dense matrix is really no longer a viable option. Since I dont need the full inverse, my thought was an iterative sparse solver might be better.

Comment: I can rattle off all sorts of details about sparse matrix formats, but haven't dug much into the inverse methods.

Comment: Do you really need the pseudoinverse itself, or are you just using it to solve a linear system? Also, what format is your sparse matrix in (CSR, CSC etc.)?

Comment: I do need the particular columns of the pseudoinverse, but I do not need the whole matrix. A is a CSR matrix.

Comment: Try Randomized SVD in [scikit-learn TruncatedSVD](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html) with various n_iter. About how big / how sparse is your A ? posdef ? Also, please add tag `sparse-matrix` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [`scipy.sparse.linalg.svds`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.svds.html) which will “Compute the largest `k` singular values/vectors for a sparse matrix” (though that’s a bit misleading since it’ll do that for dense matrixes too!).

It uses the [Arnoldi iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration) as implemented in the popular Fortran77 package, ARPACK, which in turn has wrappers in most math systems (Matlab, R, etc.).